# Oxyplot with WPF

Tags: wpf, oxyplot, lineseries

I am working with and I oxyplot download an example the following link: 
http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/03/creating-graphs-in-wpf-using-oxyplot/

I added my own data plotting to go, but the incoming points are accumulated and that makes the graph becomes unreadable.

how I do like to go update the chart so that the old points are eliminated and new points are displayed normally and not stacked.

http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/wp-content/uploads/image_thumb19.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LineSeries.Points.RemoveAt(index)`

Example:

```
(DataPlot.Series[0] as LineSeries).Points.Add(new DataPoint(xValue, yValue0));
(DataPlot.Series[1] as LineSeries).Points.Add(new DataPoint(xValue, yValue1));   
if (valueRange > 10000) //points will accumulate until the x-axis reaches 10000
    { //after 10000
     (DataPlot.Series[0] as LineSeries).Points.RemoveAt(0); //removes first point of first series
     (DataPlot.Series[1] as LineSeries).Points.RemoveAt(0); //removes first point of second series
    }
```

But you must use it together - adding one new point and removing one. Then the points will not accumulate and you will have x-axis of range you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **zoom** it. This thread from oxyplot disscusion will help you.
http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/discussions/402272